# Regex replace only if not preceded and followed by punctuation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to replace all `\n` occurrences of a text with dot, but only if they are not preceded or followed by any punctuation symbol.
In case they are preceded or followed by any punctuation symbol, they should be replaced with `''`.

```
text = "This is a sample sentence with bullets:\n    Item 1\n    Item 2\nThis is the next sentence. This is the third sentence\n."
```

Desired output:

```
"This is a sample sentence with bullets:    Item 1.    Item 2.This is the next sentence. This is the third sentence."
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Use negative lookahead and lookbehind.

Comment: I presume `''` is meant to be an empty string. It could, however, be interpreted as two single quotes or even a double quote. I would be clearer to say, "...they should be replaced with an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re

text = "This is a sample sentence with bullets:\n    Item 1\n    Item 2\nThis is the next sentence. This is the third sentence\n."
punct = set('.,;!?\'":-')

def replace(g):
    if g[1] in punct or g[2] in punct:
        return f'{g[1]}{g[2]}'
    else:
        return f'{g[1]}.{g[2]}'

text = re.sub(r'(.)\n+(.)', replace, text.strip())
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
This is a sample sentence with bullets:    Item 1.    Item 2.This is the next sentence. This is the third sentence.
```

Comment: A detail: why `text.strip()` rather than `text`? If the string were `"Three blind mice. "` wouldn't `"Three blind mice. "` be the desired return value? Also, what if the string were `"Three blind mice\n"`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, this is the reason I've put the `.strip()` there. If there is `\n` at the beginning/end of string, I remove it. The OP probably doesn't want to have `.` at the beginning/end of string. Probably I should've replaced it with `.strip('\n')` only.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re


result = re.sub(r'\n', '', re.sub(r'(?<=[^.,:;!?])\n(?=[^.,:;!?])', '.', input))
```

Here we replace `\n` surrounded by not-punctuation-symbols with `.`, and later replace all other `\n` with empty string.

But you'll need check list of not-punctuation-symbols to be suitable for your need.